# Is there an optimize way to turn a large dataframe column of lists into multiple rows (Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a script with Jupyter Notebook to transform a dataframe column composed of lists into rows (for each 9 elements in the list i want a row with each element in a different column) and i need your help. Right now i managed to make it work for a few rows (like the first hundred or in my example with three rows with index 7160, 7161, 7162), but as soon as i do it on the whole dataframe (11535 rows x 6 columns with sometimes long lists) i got major performance issues and the script run indefinitely. Is there a way to optimize my code to make it work on every row of my (large) dataframe and not just a few ? i tried also with .iterrows but the result was the same.

To summarize i would like exactly the same behavior as my code now but on the dataframe in its entirety without running indefinitely or crashing.

Here are two screenshots to help you understand :

[Right now my "df" is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w3ws.jpg) and my result ["newdf is like this"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyuQ0.jpg).
My code :

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=('index','MCC','MNC','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Altitude'), dtype=object)

#for z in df.index: <= i want this but runs indefinitely...
for z in [7160,7161,7162]: #<= working smoothly for a few rows
    MCC = df['MCC'][z]
    MNC = df['MNC'][z]
    A = df['Latitude [°]'][z]
    B = df['Longitude [°]'][z]
    C = df['Altitude (m)'][z]
    E = list(chunks(df['List'][z],9))

    i = 0
    while i < len(E):
        j = 0
        values_to_add = {'index':z, 'MCC': MCC, 'MNC': MNC, 'A': E[i][0], 'B': E[i][1], 'C': E[i][2], 'D': E[i][3], 'E': E[i][4], 'F': E[i][5], 'G': E[i][6], 'H': E[i][7], 'I': E[i][8], 'Latitude': A, 'Longitude': B, 'Altitude': C}
        row_to_add = pd.Series(values_to_add, name=i)
        newdf = pd.concat([newdf,pd.DataFrame([row_to_add])])
        i = i + 1
newdf
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df['List'].tolist()).join(df.drop(columns='List'))
```

The basic idea here is to use the column with lists as an input to a new dataframe, then put these columns back into the original dataframe (dropping the List column).

Comment: It's a good idea thanks and much more efficient and fast, but the problem is that the list on every rows contains a variety of multiple of nine values (like 9, 18, 27 etc...) and i want a new row for every nine elements. Right now with this technique i have 243 columns added to my newdf [0 to 242] instead of the nine A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I, because it must take the longest list (here 27x9=243) in all my row so it can contain every value of it.

Comment: So you'll have duplicated rows? For a multiple of nine like 27, you'd like to have 3 rows with lines columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by duplicated rows but yeah with your example of 27 I want to have 3 rows with each of the nine values in a different column (named A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I for example nine in total) and the same MCC, MNC, Latitutde, Longitude, Altitude, that was for the row with the 27 values before transformation of the row of 27 into 3 rows of 9.